# Assign a value to a variable in a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this in my program

```
for i in range(n):  
    xaux = x   
    xaux[i] = xaux[i] + h
```

and both `xaux` and `x`  are modified, how can I modify `xaux` without modifying `x`?

Comment: The code seems incomplete. `x` isn't being modified in the code you posted. Please edit the question and give us more information.

Comment: try this xaux = x[:]